# Poisson Random Variable issue

Tags: poisson-distribution, conditional-probability

I have a question in which I am confused a bit,
A shopkeeper get 'k' numbers of customers in a day which is a Poisson random variable with PMF
$$P_k(k)= \frac{u^ke^{(-u)}}{k!}$$

The probability that any customer will buy from shop is 0.3. Let M be total no. of sales on given day,

- Find conditional pmf $P_{M|K}(M|K)$
- Find for K=3, P[M=2|K=3]

What I am confused is what is the ratio factor 'U' in this case? Is it the no. of customer per day, sales per day or sales per customer?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter $u$ is the average number of people who visit the shop every day. (Note that most of these people don't buy anything.)

Comment: In that case, how can I compute U as I think no information is given for that.
Also I am correct to say that the probability 0.3 is the probability $P_{M|K}(M=1|K=1)$ ?